# Invoke custom method in Crystal report print button click

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

Using Visual studio 2008, ASP.net i have crated a Crystal report, every thing is working fine, but when i click on default print button, i need add a custom method to insert into the database. I have gone thorough the few samples those are related to windows application. please suggest me how can i do this. Thanks in an advance.

Thanks & Regards,
Jeevan.

Comment: You have to write your button for print and custom operations.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to place the crystal report viewer in a custom form designed by you. 
And then hide the print button in the crystal report viewer control from property sheet.
Then place a print button in the form and control the printing functionality using the print dialogue available in .NET

Couple of links are given below for your reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28v=VS.71%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226031%28v=VS.90%29.aspx